# Can I install a disk expansion into a Steam install?

Tags: dungeon-siege-2

I have recently bought Dungeon Siege 2 from Steam, but they don't sell the Broken World expansion.

Am I able to install the disk version of the expansion into the Steam install? Or will I need to buy it on Steam when and or if they release it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Dungeon Siege 2, my reading leads me to believe this is possible. Apparently the Disk expansion checks the system registry for the application paths so you will have to open regedit and insert the keys yourself to get this to work as per the instructions [on this thread](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1829685)

Note: Be careful about registry edits as they can seriously mess things up.

> 1. Open regedit
> 2. Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE->Software->Microsoft for 32-bit Windows and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE->SOFTWARE->WOW6432Node->Microsoft for
>      64-bit Windows.
> 3. If there is a Microsoft Games folder select it or if it doesn't exist go to Edit->New->Key and name the new folder Microsoft Games
>      (with a space between words)
> 4. Under Microsoft Games go to Edit->New->Key and name it DungeonSiege2 (no spaces)
> 5. Right click in the empty white space to the right with DungeonSiege2 selected and select New->String Value
> 6. Name this new value AppPath
> 7. Double click AppPath and enter the following as the value  C:\\Program Files\\Steam\\steamapps\\common\\dungeon siege 2 or whatever your install path happens to be
>      ***note, the double backslash is not a mistake
> 8. Create another string value called InstallationDirectory and enter the same value as above